# Why is setText not working?

Tags: java, android

So I have a `view` that is made of a single `TextView` in the middle and I change the text in this `TextView` according to the user's action, but when I use the following code:

```
if(condition == 1){
    mainText.setText("Correct");
    try {
        wait(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    int idx = r.nextInt(names.length);
    random = (names[idx]);
    mainText.setText(random);
    condition = 0;
}
```

The `mainText` doesn't change to **Correct**, but it does change to **random**.

Any idea on how to fix this, thanks

Comment: wait(2000) will help here.

Comment: You seem to block UI thread for 100ms. Doing this prevents the UI from redrawing and only _random_ value is rendered.

Comment: @SteveBenett but I only need it to be stopped for 100ms and 2seconds is a lot

Comment: @harism but I am calling it before the wait method, what should I do

Comment: You really shouldn't be pausing the UI thread. You could do the logic in a separate thread then pass the text to draw back to the UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use delays on a UI thread, it will fail 100% of the time.

Set your text, and then post a runnable to the UI thread that delays your desired time, and then changes the text.

```
view.setText("something");
view.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        view.setText("somethingelse.");
    }
}, 200);
```

Comment: what should I replace the view in the 'view.postRunnable(new Runnable(){' with?

Comment: any?
i use the one i am updating.

Comment: it's not working, I changed the view to mainText (which is a textView). and it's giving me can't resolve postRunnable error

Comment: I am not infront of an IDE, use autocomplete for a command beginning with `post` and accepts a runnable. I may be off with the name of the function. Please post back with the actual name and I can update my answer.

Comment: Just checked the docs. PLease see my update for a better implimentation.